# Linq Elements Attribute string list

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to Linq and have a problem too get a list of a specific attribute of an element.

The XML file looks like this:

```xml
<configuration>
  <logGroup>
    <group name="cpm Log 1h 1y Avg" logInterval="* 1 * * * ?" />
    <group name="cpm Log 1d 2y Avg" logInterval="* 10 * * * ?" />
  </logGroup>
  <tagGroup>
    <tag name="Tag_1">
      <property name="VALUE">
        <logGroup name="cpm Log 1h 1y Avg" />
        <logGroup name="cpm Log 1d 2y Avg" />
      </property>
    </tag>
    <tag name="Tag_2">
      <property name="VALUE">
        <logGroup name="cpm Log 1h 1y Avg" />
        <logGroup name="cpm Log 1d 2y Avg" />
      </property>
    </tag>
    <tag name="Tag_3">
      <property name="VALUE">
        <logGroup name="cpm Log 1h 1y Avg" />
        <logGroup name="cpm Log 1d 2y Avg" />
      </property>
    </tag>
  </tagGroup>
</configuration>
```

I want for get a list of an specific Tag.

So to the TAG_1 this list should be like:

```
"cpm Log 1h 1y Avg"
"cpm Log 1d 2y Avg"
```

I have tried with this code:

```
var tagLogGroups =
    from logGroupName in xelement
        .Elements("tagGroup")
        .Elements("tag")
        .Elements("property")
        .Elements("logGroup")
    where (string)logGroupName.Element("tag") == "Tag_1"
    select logGroupName.Attribute("name").Value;
```

Comment: What was wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: Is this not similar to your yesterday's [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104412/how-to-access-a-specific-attribute-using-linq-to-xml)? Please take a look at the answers and you'll be able to figure out the linq query yourself

Comment: The thing i that i can get af list of them all after each other, but i cant get af list of only the logGroup in Tag_1. @Tony Start it is almost the same question, I got the rest into lists, but not the logGroup. And i have looked at it for a long time now :(

Answer (score 1):

your `logGroupName` is a `logGroup` element. So it doesn't have a child element named `log`, I think you want:

```
where (string)logGroupName.Parent.Parent.Attribute("name") == "Tag_1"
```

Or simply (as a separate statement)

```
var tags = xelement.Descendants("tag")
    .First(x => (string) x.Attribute("name") == "Tag_1")
    .Descendants("logGroup")
    .Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("name"));
```

Comment: downvoter take your time.

Comment: I personally like to use `x.Attribute().Value` instead of `(string)x.Attribute()`, make it clearer that you want the value. (also +1).

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps you to understand better

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse("<yourXMLString>");

// step 1: get all elements with element name 'tag' from the XML using xDoc.Descendants("tag")
// step 2: now that we have all 'tag' elements, filter the one with 'name' attribute value 'Tag_1' using `where`
// step 3: now get all 'logGroup' elements wherever they are within the above filtered list
// step 4: finally get their attributes
var temp = xDoc.Descendants("tag")
                .Where(p => p.Attribute("name").Value == "Tag_1") // here p is just an iterator for results given by above statement
                .Descendants("logGroup")
                .Attributes("name");

// then you can access the fetched attributes value like below or convert to a list or whatever
string attrValue = string.Empty;
foreach (var item in temp)
{
    attrValue = item.Value;
}
```